# VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BLEND_BIT on swapchain ImageViews

Tags: c, graphics, gpu, vulkan

I updated my nVidia drivers and suddenly started getting the following validation error:

> VUID-vkCmdDrawIndexed-blendEnable-04727(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum:
> -1979288290 - Validation Error: [ VUID-vkCmdDrawIndexed-blendEnable-04727 ] Object 0: handle =
> 0x5eb05e000000003b, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_PIPELINE; | MessageID =
> 0x8a06751e | vkCmdDrawIndexed: Image view's format features of the
> color attachment (0) of the active subpass do not contain
> VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BLEND_BIT bit, but active
> pipeline's pAttachments[0].blendEnable is not VK_FALSE. The Vulkan
> spec states: If rasterization is not disabled in the bound graphics
> pipeline, then for each color attachment in the subpass, if the
> corresponding image view's format features do not contain
> VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BLEND_BIT, then the blendEnable
> member of the corresponding element of the pAttachments member of
> pColorBlendState must be VK_FALSE
> (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.211.0/windows/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-vkCmdDrawIndexed-blendEnable-04727)

Things still render correctly, but I'd like to fix the validation issue.

I am a bit confused as to how I set the VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BLEND_BIT  flag or if its part of the format vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR returns.

If it's the former, how do i set it and if it's the latter, how do i draw to it with blending enabled and not get validation errors?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I missed another validation error that gave me the clue to find the issue. I had to update the VkApplicationInfo apiVersion to VK_API_VERSION_1_3. Leaving the answer here in case it helps anyone else.

Answer (score 2):

Format features are not something you set; they're limitations that the Vulkan implementation informs you that you must work within. In particular, format features are properties that restrict how you may use any image with a particular combination of format, tiling, and so forth.

Swapchain images are subject to the same limitations as user-created images. The specification [details what the equivalent `VkImageCreateInfo` would be for a particular `vkCreateSwapchainKHR` call](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-khr-extensions/html/chap30.html#vkCreateSwapchainKHR). So those are the parameters you will need to send to `vkGetPhysicalDeviceFormatProperties` to see if your implementation supports some particular use of the swapchain image.

Blending is such a use. Apparently, whatever format you used to use allowed blending under the old driver, but this changed. And your code never verified that it was allowed.